# Can homomorphic treatment lead to disclose the context, and so break confidentiality?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

**Example:**
I want company X to perform an analysis on the data I output from a campaign of tensile testing. I send them encrypted data and ask them to fit a function between deformation and constraint (I say to X, my data is u and v), to obtain the response of my material to solicitation for future calculation

What prevents X from guessing what they are calculating, while the function they will fit is a physical response a technician will probably recognise?

(I know my example is bad cause this is a simple operation, with no need to outsource, but I have no better one)

Comment: This is looking more like a data science question, I think. Have you looked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Is this similar to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72245/can-the-person-who-decrypts-a-homomorphically-encrypted-value-know-what-operatio)?

Comment: @user In fact, my question is almost the inverse of this question. I ask if the person performing the treatment can guess the data, on the question you point, it's about the person who send the data guessing the treatment

Comment: @schroeder In my mind, the question is focused on breaking the encrytption by guessing the context out. Sounds like security, don't you think ?

Comment: I see. Well if it's homomorphic encryption then the operations will be performed on the encrypted dataset and the output will be what is contained in the (still encrypted) dataset after it is transformed, so company X never actually gets to see what the output function looks like.

Comment: @Cailloumax is the question about breaking the encryption, or using the data to find a weakness in the encryption to guess at the underlying data? Are you breaking encryption or modelling the data in order to reveal the data?

Comment: @Cailloumax crypto.stackexchange.com is better suited to answer this. They have a deeper understanding of the cryptographic properties of homomorphic encryption.